# Trouble upgrading ruby on mac high sierra

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions, homebrew

Trying to install Jekyll, I get a warning that I need Ruby 2.1. I am running 2.0.0.

I run:
 `brew upgrade ruby`

Goes through the process a bit, then throws this error:

`Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`

So I run (as prompted):

`chmod u+w /usr/local/opt /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`

then again run:

`brew upgrade ruby`

New error:

`Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0`

So I run:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0`

Then run:

`brew upgrade ruby`

and get:

`Error: ruby 2.6.3 already installed`

Okay... so I run:

`ruby -v`

and get:

`ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]`

So Ruby 2.6.3 is installed, but I'm still running 2.0.0. So I run:

`which -a ruby`

and get:

`/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby`

No sign of 2.6.3.

I'm out of my element here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Not sure how you're going to dig yourself out of the hole you're in now, but never use brew to install Ruby. Always use a Ruby manager like RVM, and **only** a Ruby manager like RVM. Should be as simple as `rvm install 2.1.10`, then `rvm use 2.1.10`, then `ruby -v`.

Comment: Even robust package managers like those on Linux OS cannot deal with multiple versions of Ruby in an appropriate way. Use [rvm](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).

Comment: @anothermh Can I not uninstall all ruby and start again? What hole exactly am I in?

Comment: The hole of having changed permissions across your filesystem & installed Ruby via brew. If you can get everything undone and switch to RVM exclusively you should be fine.

Comment: I ran the above commands because I found them here on SO – including using brew to install Ruby. Can you tell me where I changed permission across my file system?

Comment: Concerning this hole, I have system backups. Can I possibly just restore a certain directory or directories from a few days back in order to undo the damage? Or would I have to restore everything?